# Ask Different turns one year old

Tags: discussion

[image]

### On August 17, 2010, exactly one year ago today, Ask Different (then called Apple) launched into private beta.

**In the past year we’ve seen phenomenal growth. We now have:**

- 7k questions
- 13.5k answers
- 9k users
- 13.5k visits per day (average)

I just wanted to say a big “thanks” to everyone that has helped us get here today, from the people that believed in the potential of this site when it was only an [Area 51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/151/apple), to those early adopters that helped make our private and public betas successful, culminating in our launch as a full, permanent part of Stack Exchange earlier this year, to [Jin](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/6/jin), our site designer who perfectly captured the balance between Apple’s and Stack Exchange’s design aesthetic, and finally to our loyal users, who have been tirelessly helping to answer nearly any question thrown their way.

#### Here’s to many years to come!

p.s. - you early adopters should start to see your [yearling](https://apple.stackexchange.com/badges/52/yearling) badges soon!

Comment: I will admit, a better place to post this would have been our own blog.

Comment: LET US EAT CAKE!!! (err - I think that's good, no?)

Comment: Man, I wish I'd found this place when it first started. I missed the first 5 months!

Comment: There is still time for a blog post. I don't see why we couldn't get a blog post up in less than 24 hours if we had more interest in starting a blog. http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/666/is-anyone-interested-in-starting-managing-and-or-writing-for-an-ask-different-bl

Comment: Good job ladies and gents, especially to those corralling and fixing up the community while we use it. Thanks!

Comment: Where's the Facebook LIKE button?

Comment: @Martin Hm, not sure why the twitter and Facebook buttons aren't on meta

Comment: Facebook (Like), Twitter (tweet/retweet), Google (+1)

Comment: @Steve I hope we do get more people interested in contributing, enough so we can get started.

Comment: I think we can all live without the social media buttons every once in a while (writes the curmudgeon who doesn't see the point and therefore doesn't use them).

Comment: @Steve and Kyle, a [community promotion ad](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/455/community-promotion-ads-1h-2011) might be a good way to encourage people who don't hang out in meta to consider participating in the blog.

Comment: it's been a year already? grats!

Answer (score 9):

Kyle--

I just want to say congratulations on founding what has turned out to be an absolutely wonderful site, one that I feel follows Stack Exchange's ideals. I know we are all proud to help carry this site from beta to live, but you should be more so for having having the foresight and gumption to get everything started. Thank you for your lasting (and hopefully permanent) contribution to the Apple community as a whole.

I look forward to working with you, the mods, and the community on the continued growth of the site.

We rule.

Philip Regan ♦

Comment: Thanks, this site has definitely exceeded all my hopes and expectation. I'm glad I could make a lasting contribution to the Stack Exchange community and I hope to be around here for a good long while.

Comment: Oh, and I also want to thank you for all your help moderating the site. I'm really glad that there's a great amount of teamwork between our moderators, something which isn't always present on other sites.